# Why is "charge" uncountable?

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

> He shall give his angels **charge** over thee, to keep thee.

Why is *charge* uncountable here?

> God gave Joshua a **charge**.

In this case, it is countable.

I can't find authoritative sources.

Comment: Because *thee* is singular.

Comment: But countables work with singular: "He shall give bananas to thee".

Comment: What religion is that? It sounds a-peeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various senses of *charge* are given at the [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/charge) entry. Look at the tags (countable; countable/uncountable; singular) added to each.

However, three 'phrases' [I'd say idioms] containing the noun 'charge' are also given:

> in charge [of]
>
> in someone's charge
>
> take charge [of]

None of these idiomatic usages inflects.

The old-fashioned 'give them charge over' is a relative of 'in someone's charge' and similarly does not inflect. A similar idiom that *is* common today is 'give them control over', where 'control' does not inflect.